# How to redirect browser at specific date and time?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, iframe, browser

I'm trying to write a script that will allow me to redirect to a web page every Friday at a specific time.

Was hoping to have the script redirect to an Iframe for a live video feed, and after an hour, have the script also redirect to a html file that will be stored on the pc running a splash page till the next feed the following week, which will start the script again based on day and time.

Been trying for the past 3 hours to salvage something from scripts I've found on stack overflow with no success. Would GREATLY appreciate some help on this!

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what the user process is. Take me through it: I navigate to a webpage, where a splash screen gives me some sort of date time when the redirect will happen. At that exact time, if I'm on the page, the redirect takes me to another web page? Or does an iframe get created inside that page?

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will works for You.

```
function myFunction() {
   var d = new Date();
   var n = d.getDay()
   var time=.getHours()
   if(n==5)
   {
   //based on time
   if(time==14)
   {
    window.location.href="www.YourRedirectpage.com";
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (ES5 syntax):

```
Date.prototype.hour = function () {return (this.getHours())}
Date.prototype.day = function () {return (this.getDay())}
var today = new Date()

if (today.hour() == "10" && today.day() == "6") {
  // change you url here, such as; location.href ="friday url";
}
else {
  // keep (or re-attribute) your base url, such as; location.href ="base url";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want some kind of simplified job in UI which will keep watching and do redirect for you and you don't need to manually intervene much. You should use a setTimeout from Javascript to achieve this.

What this solution does that it calculates the millisecond difference between coming Friday with specific time till current date time and starts a timeout event.

Hope this is easy to understands and helps you.

GIT Repo: https://github.com/helloritesh000/how-to-redirect-browser-at-specific-date-and-time

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="RedirectTo(5, 15, 49, 30);"> <!-- RedirectTo(day(1-7(Monday)-(Sunday)),1-24 hour,1-60 min,1-60 sec) -->

<h1>This will reload redirect page</h1>
@ - <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function getNextDayOfWeek(date, dayOfWeek) {
    // Code to check that date and dayOfWeek are valid left as an exercise ;)

    var resultDate = new Date(date.getTime());

    resultDate.setDate(date.getDate() + (7 + dayOfWeek - date.getDay()) % 7);

    return resultDate;
}

function RedirectTo(day, hour, min, sec) {
  var d = new Date(getNextDayOfWeek(new Date(), day));
  d.setHours(hour);
  d.setMinutes(min);
  d.setSeconds(sec);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
  var totalMilliSecDiff = d-new Date();
  if(totalMilliSecDiff > 0)
  {
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"; }, totalMilliSecDiff);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```